# Mule SFTP endpoint fails to open local file

Tags: java, mule, sftp

I have a Mule flow that reads files through a generic inbound endpoint from an ftp server, makes some modification on the data, and writes files through a generic outbound endpoint to an sftp server. Yesterday it processed 60 files. On 57 there were no errors, but on three the following traces appeared. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
Error writing data over SFTP service, error was: Failed to open local file
4: Failed to open local file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2297)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:484)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:438)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:405)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.storeFile(SftpClient.java:385)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(SftpMessageDispatcher.java:176)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:100)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2553)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:111)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:158)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[ERROR] DispatchingLogger [Services].xmlSftpConnector.dispatcher.29 2014-06-09 15:55:07 Unexpected exception attempting to write file, message was: Failed to open local file
java.io.IOException: Failed to open local file
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.storeFile(SftpClient.java:390)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(SftpMessageDispatcher.java:176)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:100)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2553)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:111)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:158)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
[WARN] SftpUtil [Services].xmlSftpConnector.dispatcher.29 2014-06-09 15:55:07 Class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream did not implement the 'ErrorOccurred' decorator, errorOccured=true could not be set.
[ERROR] DispatchingLogger [Services].xmlSftpConnector.dispatcher.29 2014-06-09 15:55:07 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=sftp://user:<password>@server.com/folder/test/upload, connector=SftpConnector
{
  name=xmlSftpConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=cfc9fac
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[sftp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.sftp.server.com.22.folder.test.upload', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-42999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Failed to open local file (java.io.IOException)
  org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient:390 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=sftp://user:<password>@server.com/folder/test/upload, connector=SftpConnector
{
  name=xmlSftpConnector
  lifecycle=start
  this=cfc9fac
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[sftp]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.sftp.server.com.22.folder.test.upload', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={outputPattern=#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].xml}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:109 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Failed to open local file
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.storeFile(SftpClient.java:390)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(SftpMessageDispatcher.java:176)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:100)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: What are the filenames that failed?

Comment: @TracySnell:  I can't disclose the names. However, all the files were processed again successfully with the same names.

Comment: How large are the (failing) files? It appears to be a problem on your local (temp) filesystem - is that running low on free space?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup All the files are around 7k, and free space is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of 3 reasons:

1. Permissions on the folder you're writing to.
2. Spaces on the file path (or name).
3. Wrong *slash* in the file path.

**EDIT** based on comment.

You can try configuring `maxThreadsActive` to limit the no of threads active at a time.

```
<dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="5" maxThreadsIdle="5"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that wouldn't explain why when I retry the same file with the same name I don't get any failure. I think the reason could be related to the load. In fact, I never got a failure when sending files individually, only when I send a batch of around 30 I'm starting to get trouble. The problem is that I don't have any clue based on the stack trace.

Comment: I made this modification yesterday, and up to the moment the error has not appeared again. So I guess this may be a definitive solution. I'll wait a couple of days to see if the error returns, or someone has a better explanation. Otherwise the bounty is yours.

Comment: However, do you have any clue about why load would cause this particular error?

Comment: I am not sure of the definitive reason why unavailability of the threads would result in such error

Comment: I don't think it's the unavailability of threads, but the fact that many threads were writing to this sftp server at the same time what caused the error. To eliminate the error, I had to reduce the active threads to 1.